# SQL - Select only rows with one result on table with one or multiple options - Relation Table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table that has the relations of products and colors.
Each product has one or multiple colors.
Is it possible to do a query that returns only the products that have one color only ?

Sample table :

```
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | product_id | color_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        5 |
|  2 |          2 |        2 |
|  3 |          3 |        1 |
|  4 |          3 |        4 |
|  5 |          3 |        8 |
|  6 |          4 |        2 |
|  7 |          4 |        3 |
|  8 |          5 |        5 |
|  9 |          6 |        7 |
| 10 |          6 |        4 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I wish to return only the ids : 1 , 2 , 8 . (product_id : 1 , 2 , 5 )

*All values (the combinations) are unique. I cannot have two products with the same color (color_id).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `having`:

```
select product_id, max(color_id)
from t
group by product_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Works :) ! I totally forgot about ``having``

Comment: @akina yes, all values (the combinations) are unique. I cannot have two products with the same color (color_id).

Comment: hum, having is not working with where color_id = 5 (Results : 1, 5 )

Comment: @bmpf_pt [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdcc7bbcc7d610ed6c7432b70e39339e) didn't agree with you. Check yourself one more time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM table
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING MIN(color_id) = MAX(color_id)
```

Works correctly even when `(product_id, color_id)` is not defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: hum, having is not working with where color_id = 5 (Results : 1, 5 )

Comment: @bmpf_pt *having is not working with where color_id = 5 (Results : 1, 5 )* [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdcc7bbcc7d610ed6c7432b70e39339e) didn't agree with you. Check yourself one more time.

Comment: Check it now : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8b918198f1cf869ece929b11b6b95c7

Comment: @bmpf_pt Everything is correct. You select only rows which have `color_id = 5`. All such `product_id` are returned - what's wrong? PS. I see nothing about `color_id = 5` in your question... PPS. While `color_id = 5` neither GROUP BY nor HAVING needed, SELECT DISTINCT is enough (for unique `(product_id, color_id)` even DISTINCT not needed - simple SELECT).

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id, count(color_id) from table
group by product_id
having count(color_id) = 1
```

Comment: hum, having is not working with where color_id = 5 (Results : 1, 5 )

Comment: Syntax error while ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,  incorrect result otherwise.